# How to parse a json object whose elements will change?

Tags: android, json, parsing

How will I parse this JSON? For example, `pnrstatus`'s element will change.

**json**

```
{
"chartStatus": "CHART NOT PREPARED",
"to": "PUNE",
"boardingPoint": "MS",
"boardingDate": "6- 7-2016",
"pnrStatus": {
    "2": "Passenger 2:W/L 40,PQWL:W/L 25",
    "1": "Passenger 1:W/L 39,PQWL:W/L 24"
},
"reservedUpto": "PUNE",
"fare": "1030",
"class": "SL",
"from": "MS",
"trainNo": "12164",
"trainName": "CHENNAI EXP"
}
```

Comment: Convert to Hashmap or loop over the key-values is all you really can do

Comment: use JsonArray json=new JsonArray(yourjsonstring); and than simply loop thrrough all the jsonobject you want and than edit them as you like